# Generate dynamic plots with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am working on generating some plots using python, but I am generating these plots using matplotlib which is saved as images. If I create an html page as a report with these plots, they are static images. I cannot zoom in or roll over on the plot to see more detailed or specific information on a time series plot.

My question is how can I make these plots dynamic? Can someone suggest the best way to get started and move forward from there?

Answer (score 1):

You should use some additional libraries to achive your goal.

For example, there some good Python web frameworks wich you can use:

- [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) - allows you to simply write web-app with Python and you can import your plot there.
- [Plotly Python API](https://plot.ly/python/) - it would simply generate interactive plot, but store it at Plotly platform, but they provide [embeded-code option](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/embedding-plotly-graphs-in-HTML/), so you can use it on your site.

I would suggest Plotly, because it is much simpler, but it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely want to do it using `javascript`. It's by far your best option when it comes to quickly make interactive graphs that you can present to a lot of users. Any of [these](http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/) `js` libraries will do a great job.

You will then want `python` to provide the data. Depending on the `js` library you are using, you might be able to parse data from `.json`, `.csv`, etc...

If you don't need the data that makes up your plots to change (with user input, for example), then generating and saving flat files with `python` and having `javascript` parsing them from some directory might be just enough.

Otherwise, you want to take a look at a [python web framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) and use one as backend to serve the plots data by request (in that case `.json` is probably the right format).
Frameworks like [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [`CherryPy`](http://www.cherrypy.org/), [`Pyramid`](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) or even [`web2py`](http://www.web2py.com/) might be the easier ones to start with.